# Is my BCrypt variant ($2a$) fine, up to date and secure?

Tags: passwords, cryptography, hash, bcrypt

As far as I know, there are a couple of BCrypt variants and I also understood that some of those variants have security flaws so I was wondering whether it is fine or not that the library which I am using uses the $2a$ variant.
Is it secure? Is it still up to date and still can be used?
I am using bcrypt.net for c# (the new updated version on GitHub) and it uses the $2a$ prefix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is from the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt) page:

> $2a$ – The current key used to identify this scheme. Since a major security flaw was discovered in 2011 in a third-party implementation of the algorithm,[15] hashes indicated by this string are now ambiguous and might have been generated by the flawed implementation, or a subsequent fixed, implementation. The flaw may be triggered by some password strings containing non-ASCII characters, such as specially crafted password strings.

In case you'll be looking for alternatives, I'd recommend PBKDF2 with SHA512 and 5k - 10k iteration rounds. Should be enough to make brute-forcing too costly and still run your apps without notable delay. [Here](https://github.com/ctz/fastpbkdf2) is an off-the-shelf c# implementation.